# What is the difference between a tab stop and a tab width?

Tags: indentation, tabs

**Greetings**

lately I've been trying to learn Emacs and configure it as an IDE, so I started learning the basics, until I got to the segment of configuring indentations.

I do understand that the term **Tab stop**, means, well, where tabs stop.
So if we are able to set stop points for a tab, then **why do we need tab widths**?

I would be glad if a professional would be able to point me in the right direction, because I cannot understand the difference between the terms **tab stop** and **tab width**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have both because a text editor is not a typewriter, basically.

The `tab-width` tells Emacs how to display a tab *character* in the buffer.  A tab width of 8 causes Emacs to render a tab character the equivalent width as up to 8 spaces.  For a line which started with a tab, it would have the appearance of 8 spaces.  For a line which started with 6 spaces and then a tab, the tab would have the visual appearance of 2 spaces.  The important thing is that a tab character is a specific kind of textual data in a digital format.

For "tab stops", you want to think of a physical analogue typewriter -- you hit the tab key and the carriage moves to the next tab stop position.  There's no concept of a tab *character* here because it's just a distance across a sheet of paper.  Tab stops in Emacs are analogous -- they just say where to move the cursor to, and they have no bearing on which digital *characters* are used to get it there -- you might need *many* space and/or tab characters to reach the next tab stop position.  Your `tab-stop-list` might be implicit (multiples of `tab-width`) or it might be an explicit list of arbitrary positions.

If `indent-tabs-mode` is non-nil, then moving to a tab stop may involve a mixture of tab characters and space characters, with the tabs generally occupying the same amount of space as `tab-width` spaces would.

Finally, what the `TAB` *key* on your keyboard does is another matter again.  It could do anything, but typically it's configured to perform indentation in some way, and that *might* cause it to convert space characters to tab characters.

---

Summary:

- A tab stop is just a column position (to which certain commands will move the cursor).
- A tab *character* (ascii character code 9) is something that might appear in your text buffer.
- The `tab-width` variable tells Emacs how to *display* a tab character.
- In the absence of an *explicit* `tab-stop-list`, the `tab-width` variable also determines the *implicit* tab stops.
- Indenting is complicated, and what happens when you type the TAB key can vary greatly in different circumstances.

---

Further reading:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Tab Stops`

  > Note that the tab stops discussed in this section have nothing to do
  > with how tab characters are displayed in the buffer.  Tab characters are
  > always displayed as empty spaces extending to the next “display tab
  > stop”.  *Note Text Display::.
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Text Display`

  > The ASCII character set contains non-printing “control characters”.
  > Two of these are displayed specially: the newline character (Unicode
  > code point U+000A) is displayed by starting a new line, while the tab
  > character (U+0009) is displayed as a space that extends to the next tab
  > stop column (normally every 8 columns).  The number of spaces per tab is
  > controlled by the buffer-local variable ‘tab-width’, which must have an
  > integer value between 1 and 1000, inclusive.  Note that the way the tab
  > character in the buffer is displayed has nothing to do with the
  > definition of <TAB> as a command.
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Indentation`

  > The simplest way to perform indentation is the <TAB> key.  In most
  > major modes, this runs the command ‘indent-for-tab-command’.  (In C and
  > related modes, <TAB> runs the command ‘c-indent-line-or-region’, which
  > behaves similarly, *note C Indent::).
  >
  > <TAB>
  > Insert whitespace, or indent the current line, in a
  > mode-appropriate way (‘indent-for-tab-command’).  If the region is
  > active, indent all the lines within it.
  >
  > The exact behavior of <TAB> depends on the major mode.  In Text mode
  > and related major modes, <TAB> normally inserts some combination of
  > space and tab characters to advance point to the next tab stop (*note
  > Tab Stops::).  For this purpose, the position of the first
  > non-whitespace character on the preceding line is treated as an
  > additional tab stop, so you can use <TAB> to align point with the
  > preceding line.  If the region is active (*note Using Region::), <TAB>
  > acts specially: it indents each line in the region so that its first
  > non-whitespace character is aligned with the preceding line.
  >
  > In programming modes, <TAB> indents the current line of code in a way
  > that makes sense given the code in the preceding lines.  If the region
  > is active, all the lines in the region are indented this way.  If point
  > was initially within the current line’s indentation, it is repositioned
  > to the first non-whitespace character on the line.
  >
  > If you just want to insert a tab character in the buffer, type ‘C-q
  > <TAB>’ (*note Inserting Text::).